# Can a "handy" person remove and replace the rear spoiler on a 2004 Toyota 4runner

Tags: toyota, body-work, 4runner

I have to have the rear spoiler (above the rear hatch back window) replaced.
Apparently two of the three tabs are broken.  The dealer wants $$$ to do this.
Can a handy person remove and replace that unit?

Comment: Absolutely.  A mindful handy person can complete this job.

Comment: @DucatiKiller, ha! that could actually be the answer. Carol - If you want more assistance, then you could post pictures ! Close ups would be nice

Comment: As chilljeet stated, pictures would be great! We would really like to help you out here. It's just as the question is written, it is *very* subjective and ripe for closure. Please help us to help you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible to do yourself. If you already have the new spoiler check and see if it came with new mounting hardware for the vehicle.

1. Open and raise the rear liftgate.
2. On the inside near the top corners you should see two plastic trim plugs, one for each side. Remove both of these carefully using a plastic tool.
3. Using a 10mm socket wrench remove the bolts inside both holes.
4. Disconnect the wiring harness on the driver's side of the vehicle.
5. Push up on the spoiler from outside the liftgate from both sides. It will slide out of the locks and be able to remove.

This is one of the easier processes I've seen for removing a piece of vehicle trim. It shouldn't take more than a few minutes, especially with someone to help with lifting it off the car.

Answer (score 1):

If the spoiler has been in place for a few years, it is likely that the contacting paint surfaces will have adhered, and pulling the freshly unbolted spoiler away from the trunk lid will pull some body paint with it.  To minimize (probably not eliminate) the necessary resurfacing of the trunk lid, apply a little penetrating oil or detergent to the lines of contact, loosen the bolts, wait a few hours, and gently wiggle the spoiler loose.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!